# NullPointerException in WebDriverBackedSelenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium and still exploring it. I'm trying to test an ajax element on a site. On clicking the element some text pops on some area on the page. I've run this test on RC as well as WebDriver. It's working fine. Now I want(just out of curiosity) to test it via WebDriverBackedSelenium. But it's throwing an error. The code is:

```
    import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium;
    import org.openqa.selenium.internal.WrapsDriver;
    import org.junit.After;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;


    public class CheckElements extends SeleneseTestBase {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        String baseUrl = "path/to/the/site";
        WebDriver driver = ((WrapsDriver) selenium).getWrappedDriver();
        selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
    }
```

The error is:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
             at com.CheckElements.setUp(CheckElements.java:17)
```

I believe the main problem is in setup method. I'm using selenium standalone server 2.0 and junit 4.7. Can you please tell where am I going wrong?

Another Question??

If I write the same test as below, the test runs fine but it doesn't give error even if the text doesn't matches what is required.

```
    import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium;
    import org.junit.After;
    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;


     public class New extends SeleneseTestBase {

      WebDriver driver;
      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      String baseUrl = "path/to/the/link";
      selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
  }
```

I hope I'm clear in my questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly expect this to be the issue:

```
WebDriver driver = ((WrapsDriver) selenium).getWrappedDriver();
```

The driver instance is probably null.

The difference being in your other test, you are explicitly creating it into a FirefoxDriver:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Comment: Sorry but can you explain it more? I mean, everywhere I searched I found it the same way. What changes can I make here?

Comment: I am not the best Java person. However "WebDriver driver = ((WrapsDriver) selenium).getWrappedDriver();" will fail because you are giving 'selenium' a value AFTER that, so when it tries to call it, it'll be null - selenium is null until the line AFTER it. Try changing it to "WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();"